# How can I easily find Shadow Orbs?

Tags: terraria

I've been trying to find shadow orbs so I can spawn in the Eater of Worlds. What's the fastest way to locate them?

Comment: You need hardmode souls to craft the megashark, and yet you're preparing to battle the Wall of Flesh? Am I missing a teeny tiny crucial detail here?

Comment: What @Gigazelle says is true. You cannot craft a Megashark until after you defeat Wall of Flesh.

Comment: Let's assume the OP meant the [Minishark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Minishark) which, as indeed pointed out, does not require the [Illegal Gun Parts](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Illegal_Gun_Parts)

Comment: Ok,ok,I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shadow Orbs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb) are always in the Corruption biome. If you see a vertical chasm in rock, at the bottom of it there will almost always be a Shadow Orb.

Alternatively, to summon Eater of Worlds you can craft [Worm Food](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Worm_Food) using 30 [Vile Powder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vile_Powder) and 15 [Rotten Chunks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rotten_Chunk) at a [Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar).

Comment: Would like to add that you need to break through some Ebonstone (using bombs or a Nightmare Pickaxe or better) before actually reaching the Orb.

Comment: @Doktoro Or you can just use the dust from the Dryad to remove the corruption above it.

Answer (score -2):

If you see a hole covered in purple cobblestone (this is easier if you fly or grapple down) go down. You will often find a purple ball (the shadow orb). Break it using a hammer.